# Why app crashing because of a missing dimension (for google maps) only when I apply changes?

Tags: android, google-maps

My app is crashing only when I apply changes (not when I run the app) and it fails in a fragment where I am loading google maps. The error given is as follows:

```
Process: com.locatecars.findspot, PID: 20722
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locatecars.findspot/com.locatecars.findspot.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.locatecars.findspot:dimen/card_icon_multiline_padding_bottom" (7f060059) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0xc30c21 a=3 r=0x7f060059}
```

And the method where this error is pointing me to is this:

```
private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }
        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle); //<-- this line in particular
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        if (geoApiContext == null) {
            geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(getString(R.string.google_api_key)).build();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
Here is the snippet after the suggestion from Chris

```
Bundle mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState != null ?
                savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY) : new Bundle();
        savedInstanceState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
```

**Edit 2**

After mulling over Chris's answer again, this is what is working:

```
Bundle mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState != null ?
                savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY) : new Bundle();
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a null Bundle. Try something like this instead:

```
Bundle mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState != null ? 
  savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY) : new Bundle();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was able to replicate the problem once again despite your suggestion Chris. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or perhaps I implemented your suggestion incorrectly.